# execvp not giving output

Tags: c, exec

I have to program a little shell for school but I am stuck at even executing a command.
execvp worked when I executed it in the wait for input function, but in the execute command function it doesnt e.g I don't get any output to stdout for commands like `ls`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int executecommand(char commandarray[]){
    char * command = &commandarray[0];
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        perror("failed");
        return errno;
    } else if (0 == pid) {
        execvp(command, &commandarray);
        return 0;
    } else {
        int waitstatus;
        waitpid(pid, &waitstatus, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}

int waitforinput(){
    printf("$ ");
    char cmd[256];
    fgets(cmd, 256, stdin);
    executecommand(cmd);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    waitforinput();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `commandarray` should be an array of pointers, not a single string. It becomes the `argv` array of the new process.

Comment: You should check for errors from `execvp()`.

Comment: @Barmar could you elaborate, and also how would I go on and fix this?

Comment: The string returned by `fgets()` ends with a newline. You need to remove that before trying to use it as a command, because the program name doesn't have a newline in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `execvp()` must be an array of strings ending with `NULL`, not a pointer to a single string. Normally you would parse the input line into an array containing the command followed by arguments, but if you don't care about arguments you can just create an array with 2 elements, the command followed by `NULL`.

You also need to remove the newline from the end of the input line returned by `fgets()`. See [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) for many ways to do this.

If you want to return `errno`, you need to save it before calling `perror()`, because that may change `errno`.

```
int executecommand(char *commandarray[]){
    char * command = commandarray[0];
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        int saved_errno = errno;
        perror("fork");
        return saved_errno;
    } else if (0 == pid) {
        execvp(command, commandarray);
        int saved_errno = errno;
        perror("execvp");
        return saved_errno;
    } else {
        int waitstatus;
        waitpid(pid, &waitstatus, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}

int waitforinput(){
    printf("$ ");
    char cmd[256];
    char *cmd_array[2];
    fgets(cmd, 256, stdin);
    cmd[strcspn(cmd, "\n")] = 0; // remove trailing newline
    cmd_array[0] = cmd;
    cmd_array[1] = NULL;
    return executecommand(cmd_array);
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your changes and it does work for `ls` now but not for commands with argument like `ls /`

Comment: I explained that in my answer. You have no code to parse the input line into multiple arguments.

Comment: I'm not going to write that for you. Use `strtok()` to split the input.

Comment: @Jocomol Give this a read: https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

### Invalid arguments to `execvp` :

From the man page:

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[])
```

> **The execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of
> pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list
> available to the new program.** The first argument, by convention,
> should point to the filename associated with the file being executed.
> **> The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer**.

The `execvp` function expects an array of strings terminated by a `NULL` pointer, not a pointer to one string.

---

### Ignoring the return value of `exec`* and others:

> The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred. The return
> value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

Add a check for that.

Likewise, `waitpid()` may also fail, check its return value.

You also declared `waitforinput()` and `executecommand()` to return an `int`, but ignore the values returned. Either make use of them, or change the return type to `void`.

---

### Trailing newline:

```
fgets(cmd, 256, stdin)
```

`fgets` will retain the newline in the buffer. Here's a one-liner that I use to remove it¹:

```
cmd [strcspn (cmd, "\n\r")] = `\0`;
```

---

**Aside:** Change

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

to

```
int main (void)
```

as you never make use of the arguments.

[1] — Here are some others: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67608/265278